# How can I scroll list keeping items always at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this for a while.  I am trying to create an html/css "chat style" ul list that loads all items from the bottom. I have tried several attempts using scroll tracking event that scroll to bottom, but they all load from the top and don't start scrolling to bottom until there is a scroll bar (of course).  What I want is a list that loads items from the bottom and then stays at the bottom.
TIA for any help.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006900/align-text-with-bottom-as-it-comes-in-during-a-chat

Comment: [this answer presents a hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681192/how-to-align-a-list-of-elements-to-bottom/40681582#40681582) that might help you (the list order and scroll direction reverses though)

Comment: Thanks.  My divs are not fixed height so it presents some challenge.